# What is the difference between elemental.json and com.google.json library?

Tags: java, json, vaadin, vaadin7

Why do we have elemental.json library over com.google.json?

I'm struggling with the creation of JsonArray in Vaadin 7.

In Json.createArray() there is no add method. How can I create a json array?

I want to create an array like:

```
var shapeArray = 
[
    {type: 'rectangle', x:50, y:50, width : 50, height: 50},
    {type: 'circle', x:75, y:150,  r : 20}, 
    {type: 'rectangle', x:50, y:200, width : 100, height: 20},
    {type: 'circle', x:75, y:300,  r : 30}, 
];
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this official statement](http://vaadin.com/download/release/7.4/7.4.0/release-notes.html#incompatible), starting with 7.4.0 `elemental.json.*` replaces the old packages.

I've played around a bit as I also had to adapt to these changes and I found at least these 2 possibilities:

```
import elemental.json.Json;
import elemental.json.JsonArray;
import elemental.json.JsonValue;
import elemental.json.impl.JsonUtil;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JsonTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldParseJson() {
        JsonArray array = JsonUtil.parse("[\n" +
                "    {'type': 'rectangle', 'x':50, 'y':50, 'width': 50, 'height': 50},\n" +
                "    {'type': 'circle', 'x':75, 'y':150,  'r' : 20}, \n" +
                "    {'type': 'rectangle', 'x':50, 'y':200, 'width' : 100, 'height': 20},\n" +
                "    {'type': 'circle', 'x':75, 'y':300,  'r' : 30}, \n" +
                "]");


        System.out.println("Parsed string array:\n" + JsonUtil.stringify(array, 2));
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldCreateArray() {
        //for the sake of brevity I'll create the object by also parsing a string, but you get the general idea
        JsonValue object = JsonUtil.parse("{'type': 'rectangle', 'x':50, 'y':50, 'width': 50, 'height': 50}");
        JsonArray array = Json.createArray();
        array.set(0, object);

        System.out.println("Manually created array:\n" + JsonUtil.stringify(array, 2));
    }
}
```

Which output

```
Parsed string array:
[
  {
    "type": "rectangle",
    "x": 50,
    "y": 50,
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50
  },
  {
    "type": "circle",
    "x": 75,
    "y": 150,
    "r": 20
  },
  {
    "type": "rectangle",
    "x": 50,
    "y": 200,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 20
  },
  {
    "type": "circle",
    "x": 75,
    "y": 300,
    "r": 30
  }
]
```

and

```
Manually created array:
[
  {
    "type": "rectangle",
    "x": 50,
    "y": 50,
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same situation, so should i conclude that vaadin elemantal.json is not compitable with google gson as gson is compitable with org.json.  And i'll have to make necessary adaptions to my code wherever org.json is being used/converted into google gson json

Comment: @Abhishek-M You need to make necessary adaptations so that the `org.json.*` and `com.google.gwt.json.*` packages&classes will been replaced by `elemental.json.*`.